# Facebook share show image in popup, but not in timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know there are a lot questions simillar to mine. But non of them helped me.
My site is on opencart, when press share button, a popup come up with an image. But the image disapear after been shared on facebook, it just leave a blank square.
I put the following meta og tags in head:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="I Love Bombshell Bums">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://http://www.bombshellbums.com/I-love-bombshell-bums-shirt">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.bombshellbums.com/image/cache/data/I_love_bombshell_colours-630x630.jpg">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Bombshell Bums"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="669535109829867"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="This styled shirt is a spin off to the traditional &quot;I heart NY&quot; T-shirts. The &quot;I Love Bombshell Bums&quot; shirts shows your appreciation to nice butts. Available in a range of sizes and colours">
```

In facebook debugger footer, the image is showing there, but I also receive the warning messages:

```
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

When I click on Scraped URL, the meta og: tags are not showing in the source code.
I don't know if this is just facebook cache thing or I did something wrong on the website.

This is the link: http://www.bombshellbums.com/I-love-bombshell-bums-shirt

Anyone any ideas please??

This is really wield. whatever content I put in body, it shows in facebook scrap url. But the og tag I put in head is just not showing at all. does facebook only refresh page content, not head?

Comment: This is what Facebook sees: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bombshellbums.com%2FI-love-bombshell-bums-shirt . You are sure that the tags are there for all requests?

Comment: Thank you, Wizkid:
Yes, If you check the source code of that page, you would see meta og tags are below the <title> tag, somehow it just not showing on facebook scraped url.

Comment: But the HTML code is completely different when Facebook fetches it. You are sure that you are not doing different things depending on web browser?

Comment: Hi Wizkid: I just checked the site. Found it's very wield that when I change a website content, the new content comes up on facebook scraped url. But when I make change on <head>, the content in facebook scraped remained same.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. Thank you Wizkid, you inspired me.